# how to use for loop to get number of total duplicates in all columns of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Dataframe Example: https://www.screencast.com/t/6bxST8Fn

I am trying to find how many duplicate records exist in each column of a pandas dataframe. I thought I could simply use the `df.[column name].duplicated().sum()` code in a for loop like below but got an invalid syntax error for duplicated().

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column].duplicated().sum()
```

**My specific goal:** Could someone please tell me what is the correct syntax? If however, my approach to doing this is completely incorrect, what's the alternative to a for loop that will accomplish the same thing?

I'm hoping to get the output in the following format:
Name of column: Total number of duplicates in the column

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicate records in each column?" It seems you're just asking for the number of times each value in a given column occurs in that column.

Comment: Column A     Column B     Column C
 Mazda            Sony              Dell
 Mazda            Apple              HP
 Toyota            Sony            Toshiba

Column A has 2 duplicates, Column B has 2 duplicates, and Column C has 0.

Comment: Please add *and format* what your data look like in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Realized that after entering. Trying to figure out how this site works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You'll get better help, faster, if you post a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  In particular, consider including example data that are representative of `df`, along with expected output.

Comment: @blacksite just added an example dataframe at the top of the post.

Comment: @techscolasticus just copy-paste the actual data from your Excel sheet. Please don't post pictures of your data; makes it more difficult for someone to simply pop in an answer your question quickly.

Comment: @blacksite I can't embed pictures because I don't have 10 reputation.

Comment: See my answer below, but it's literally copy-pasting data from Excel. Select your data. Copy it. Go into the question editor. Paste it. Save edits. Done. Steer clear of pictures -- you'll raise your chances of getting an answer tenfold.

Comment: This is obviously not your actual code as there are no syntax errors associated with it. Please show us your code.

Comment: @techscolasticus What do you think of my solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': ['M', 'M', 'T', 'T', 'C']})

dupes = {}

for c in df:
    gb = df.groupby(c).size()
    dupes[c] = gb[gb > 1].sum()
```

`dupes` is now:

```
>>> dupes
{'Car': 4}
```

Just apply that logic to your full dataframe.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help.
I tried copy/pasting my data from Excel and it looked exactly like my comment.

Comment: After that, just highlight the text and hit `Ctrl`+`K` to format it like code. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities) for more details. Welcome to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution will be based on value counts to get rid of for loops. i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': ['M', 'M', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C'],'TV':['So','Su','So', 'So','T','So'],'Computer': ['D','Hp','Ap','Ac','S','H']})


x = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
dupes_count = x[x>1].fillna(0).sum().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Car': 5, 'Computer': 0, 'TV': 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) first with `apply` for all columns, then replace unique (`1`) values to `0` and `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Car': list('MMTTCT'),
                  'Computer':list('abbbbc'),
                  'TV':list('aaabbb')})

print (df.apply(pd.value_counts))
   Car  Computer   TV
C  1.0       NaN  NaN
M  2.0       NaN  NaN
T  3.0       NaN  NaN
a  NaN       1.0  3.0
b  NaN       4.0  3.0
c  NaN       1.0  NaN

dupes = df.apply(pd.value_counts).replace(1,0).sum().astype(int).to_dict()
print (dupes)
 {'Car': 5, 'TV': 6, 'Computer': 4}
```

Comment: Almost similar removing the redunant functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can groupby on all the columns and call size the index indicates the duplicate values:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(),as_index=False).size()

one    three  two  
False  False  True     1
True   False  False    2
       True   True     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for column in df.columns:
    duplicate_column = df[column].duplicated().sum()
    print(column,': ', duplicate_column)
```

This works for me.